# Type is not defined

Tags: 2010, javascript

The .js file is loaded in aspx page like this:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" ID="script1" name="/js/my.js" Localizable="false" />
```

And when page is loaded throws javascript exception

> Type is not defined

**EDIT** This script load line works:

```
<script src="/_layouts/js/my.js"/>
```

The `ScriptLink` control produces correct `<script>` link,the problem is that its placed higher in the page then some of the other SharePoint scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both`ScriptLink` and native

```
<script src="/_layouts/js/my.js"/>
```

works, though `ScriptLink` control transformed HTML code is placed **higher** in the page then SharePoint SOD scripts that `my.js` depends on -> it executes before SP SOD scripts.

Comment: So the answer was to go with the native link, then, sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you add incorrect reference to the JS file. See [this post](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Refer-Scripts-and-CSS-Style-Sheet-in-SharePoint-2013-Visual-Web-Part-and-Master-Page.aspx) to understand the common practice.

Comment: Best not to answer with links, without summarizing what is there. That link is now a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the javascript code inside a Content Query Web Part on that page?